# What is checkcons in linux/unix

Tags: linux, unix, mips, linux-device-driver

could it be check constraints like with an sql server? what .h would this be defined in. This is reverse engineered with ghidra im still wondering why ghidra represents all move instructions as _or but it wont let me edit it.

```auto
*************************************************************
*                           FUNCTION                        * 
*************************************************************
                         bool  __stdcall  usb_pckm_checkcons (longlong  param_1 )
         bool              v0_lo:1        <RETURN>
         longlong          a0:8           param_1
         undefined8        Stack[-0x10]   local_10                                XREF[2]:     00103ae0 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103af8 (R)   
         undefined8        Stack[-0x18]   local_18                                XREF[2]:     00103ad4 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103afc (R)   
         undefined8        Stack[-0x20]   local_20                                XREF[4]:     00103b18 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103b5c (R) , 
                                                                                               00103bcc (R) , 
                                                                                               00103c50 (R)   
         undefined8        Stack[-0x28]   local_28                                XREF[4]:     00103be4 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103be8 (R) , 
                                                                                               00103c18 (R) , 
                                                                                               00103c6c (W)   
         undefined8        Stack[-0x30]   local_30                                XREF[2]:     00103b54 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103cc0 (R)   
         undefined8        Stack[-0x38]   local_38                                XREF[2]:     00103bf8 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103c14 (R)   
         undefined8        Stack[-0x40]   local_40                                XREF[2]:     00103c84 (W) , 
                                                                                               00103c90 (R)   
                         usb_pckm_checkcons                              XREF[2]:     Entry Point (*) , 
                                                                                      usb_hid_attach:00102078 (c)   
    00103ad0 67  bd  fe       daddiu     sp ,sp ,-0x150
             b0
    00103ad4 ff  b0  01       sd         s0 ,local_18 (sp )
             38
    00103ad8 00  80  80       or         s0 ,param_1 ,zero
             25
    00103adc 10  80  00       beq        param_1 ,zero ,LAB_00103af4
             05
    00103ae0 ff  bf  01       _sd        ra ,local_10 (sp )
             40
    00103ae4 8c  81  00       lw         at ,0x4 (param_1 )
             04
    00103ae8 30  21  00       andi       at ,at ,0x40
             40
    00103aec 24  02  00       li         v0 ,0x40
             40
    00103af0 10  22  00       beq        at ,v0 ,LAB_00103b08
             05
                         LAB_00103af4                                    XREF[1]:     00103adc (j)   
    00103af4 00  00  10       _or        v0 ,zero ,zero
             25
                         LAB_00103af8                                    XREF[9]:     00103b38 (j) ,  00103b88 (j) , 
                                                                                      00103b90 (j) ,  00103b98 (j) , 
                                                                                      00103c44 (j) ,  00103ca0 (j) , 
                                                                                      00103ccc (j) ,  00103cd4 (j) , 
                                                                                      00103cdc (j)   
    00103af8 df  bf  01       ld         ra ,local_10 (sp )
             40
    00103afc df  b0  01       ld         s0 ,local_18 (sp )
             38
    00103b00 03  e0  00       jr         ra
             08
    00103b04 67  bd  01       _daddiu    sp ,sp ,0x150
             50
                         LAB_00103b08                                    XREF[1]:     00103af0 (j)   
    00103b08 df  84  67       ld         param_1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103b0c 0c  04  18       jal        kopt_find                                        undefined kopt_find()
             3e
    00103b10 64  84  04       _daddiu    param_1 ,param_1 ,0x488
             88
    00103b14 14  40  00       bne        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103b40
             0a
    00103b18 ff  a2  01       _sd        v0 ,local_20 (sp )
             30
                         LAB_00103b1c                                    XREF[1]:     00103b50 (j)   
    00103b1c df  84  57       ld         param_1 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
    00103b20 10  80  00       beq        param_1 ,zero ,LAB_00103b90
             1b
    00103b24 24  02  00       _li        v0 ,0x1
             01
    00103b28 0c  04  10       jal        usb_pckm_is_better_defkbd                        bool usb_pckm_is_better_defkbd(l
             9e
    00103b2c 02  00  28       _or        a1 ,s0 ,zero
             25
    00103b30 10  40  00       beq        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103b98
             19
    00103b34 24  02  00       _li        v0 ,0x1
             01
    00103b38 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             ef
    00103b3c ff  90  57       _sd        s0 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
                         LAB_00103b40                                    XREF[1]:     00103b14 (j)   
    00103b40 df  85  67       ld         a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103b44 00  40  20       or         param_1 ,v0 ,zero
             25
    00103b48 0c  04  18       jal        strstr                                           char * strstr(char * __haystack,
             40
    00103b4c 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x968
             68
    00103b50 10  40  ff       beq        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103b1c
             f2
    00103b54 ff  a2  01       _sd        v0 ,local_30 (sp )
             20
    00103b58 df  85  67       ld         a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103b5c df  a4  01       ld         param_1 ,local_20 (sp )
             30
    00103b60 0c  04  18       jal        strcmp                                           int strcmp(char * __s1, char * _
             1c
    00103b64 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x930
             30
    00103b68 14  40  00       bne        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103ba0
             0d
    00103b6c df  84  57       _ld        param_1 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
    00103b70 10  80  00       beq        param_1 ,zero ,LAB_00103b88
             05
    00103b74 24  02  00       _li        v0 ,0x1
             01
    00103b78 0c  04  10       jal        usb_pckm_is_better_defkbd                        bool usb_pckm_is_better_defkbd(l
             9e
    00103b7c 02  00  28       _or        a1 ,s0 ,zero
             25
    00103b80 10  40  00       beq        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103cd4
             54
    00103b84 24  02  00       _li        v0 ,0x1
             01
                         LAB_00103b88                                    XREF[1]:     00103b70 (j)   
    00103b88 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             db
    00103b8c ff  90  57       _sd        s0 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
                         LAB_00103b90                                    XREF[1]:     00103b20 (j)   
    00103b90 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             d9
    00103b94 ff  90  57       _sd        s0 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
                         LAB_00103b98                                    XREF[1]:     00103b30 (j)   
    00103b98 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             d7
    00103b9c 00  00  10       _or        v0 ,zero ,zero
             25
                         LAB_00103ba0                                    XREF[1]:     00103b68 (j)   
    00103ba0 0c  04  18       jal        usb_iface_device                                 undefined usb_iface_device()
             0e
    00103ba4 de  04  00       _ld        param_1 ,0x88 (s0 )
             88
    00103ba8 0c  04  18       jal        usb_device_path                                  undefined usb_device_path()
             44
    00103bac 00  40  20       _or        param_1 ,v0 ,zero
             25
    00103bb0 00  40  30       or         a2 ,v0 ,zero
             25
    00103bb4 df  85  67       ld         a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103bb8 66  07  00       daddiu     a3 ,s0 ,0x58
             58
    00103bbc 67  a4  00       daddiu     param_1 ,sp ,0x0
             00
    00103bc0 0c  04  18       jal        sprintf                                          int sprintf(char * __s, char * _
             7e
    00103bc4 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x970
             70
    00103bc8 df  85  67       ld         a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103bcc df  a4  01       ld         param_1 ,local_20 (sp )
             30
    00103bd0 0c  04  18       jal        strstr                                           char * strstr(char * __haystack,
             40
    00103bd4 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x948
             48
    00103bd8 10  40  00       beq        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103c4c
             1c
    00103bdc 64  46  00       _daddiu    a2 ,v0 ,0xb
             0b
    00103be0 10  c0  00       beq        a2 ,zero ,LAB_00103c70
             23
    00103be4 ff  a6  01       _sd        a2 ,local_28 (sp )
             28
                         LAB_00103be8                                    XREF[1]:     00103c68 (j)   
    00103be8 df  a4  01       ld         param_1 ,local_28 (sp )
             28
    00103bec 0c  04  18       jal        strchr                                           char * strchr(char * __s, int __
             86
    00103bf0 24  05  00       _li        a1 ,0x2f
             2f
    00103bf4 24  05  00       li         a1 ,0x10
             10
    00103bf8 ff  a2  01       sd         v0 ,local_38 (sp )
             18
    00103bfc 0c  04  18       jal        bzero                                            void bzero(void * __s, size_t __
             4a
    00103c00 67  a4  01       _daddiu    param_1 ,sp ,0x100
             00
    00103c04 df  85  67       ld         a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103c08 67  a4  01       daddiu     param_1 ,sp ,0x100
             00
    00103c0c 0c  04  18       jal        strcat                                           char * strcat(char * __dest, cha
             24
    00103c10 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x978
             78
    00103c14 df  a6  01       ld         a2 ,local_38 (sp )
             18
    00103c18 df  a7  01       ld         a3 ,local_28 (sp )
             28
    00103c1c 67  a5  01       daddiu     a1 ,sp ,0x100
             00
    00103c20 00  e0  20       or         param_1 ,a3 ,zero
             25
    00103c24 00  c7  30       dsubu      a2 ,a2 ,a3
             2f
    00103c28 0c  04  18       jal        bcopy                                            void bcopy(void * __src, void * 
             88
    00103c2c 64  c6  00       _daddiu    a2 ,a2 ,0x1
             01
    00103c30 67  a5  01       daddiu     a1 ,sp ,0x100
             00
    00103c34 0c  04  18       jal        strstr                                           char * strstr(char * __haystack,
             40
    00103c38 67  a4  00       _daddiu    param_1 ,sp ,0x0
             00
    00103c3c 14  40  00       bne        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103cac
             1b
    00103c40 df  85  67       _ld        a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103c44 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             ac
    00103c48 00  00  10       _or        v0 ,zero ,zero
             25
                         LAB_00103c4c                                    XREF[1]:     00103bd8 (j)   
    00103c4c df  85  67       ld         a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103c50 df  a4  01       ld         param_1 ,local_20 (sp )
             30
    00103c54 0c  04  18       jal        strstr                                           char * strstr(char * __haystack,
             40
    00103c58 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x958
             58
    00103c5c 10  40  00       beq        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103c74
             05
    00103c60 df  84  57       _ld        param_1 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
    00103c64 64  46  00       daddiu     a2 ,v0 ,0xb
             0b
    00103c68 14  c0  ff       bne        a2 ,zero ,LAB_00103be8
             df
    00103c6c ff  a6  01       _sd        a2 ,local_28 (sp )
             28
                         LAB_00103c70                                    XREF[1]:     00103be0 (j)   
    00103c70 df  84  57       ld         param_1 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
                         LAB_00103c74                                    XREF[1]:     00103c5c (j)   
    00103c74 10  80  00       beq        param_1 ,zero ,LAB_00103cac
             0d
    00103c78 df  85  67       _ld        a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103c7c 0c  04  10       jal        usb_pckm_module_id                               undefined8 usb_pckm_module_id(vo
             e4
    00103c80 00  00  00       _nop
             00
    00103c84 ff  a2  01       sd         v0 ,local_40 (sp )
             10
    00103c88 0c  04  10       jal        usb_pckm_module_id                               undefined8 usb_pckm_module_id(vo
             e4
    00103c8c 02  00  20       _or        param_1 ,s0 ,zero
             25
    00103c90 df  a7  01       ld         a3 ,local_40 (sp )
             10
    00103c94 00  e2  38       slt        a3 ,a3 ,v0
             2a
    00103c98 10  e0  00       beq        a3 ,zero ,LAB_00103cac
             04
    00103c9c df  85  67       _ld        a1 ,0x6778 (gp )
             78
    00103ca0 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             95
    00103ca4 00  00  10       _or        v0 ,zero ,zero
             25
    00103ca8 df              ??         DFh
    00103ca9 85              ??         85h
    00103caa 67              ??         67h    g
    00103cab 78              ??         78h    x
                         LAB_00103cac                                    XREF[3]:     00103c3c (j) ,  00103c74 (j) , 
                                                                                      00103c98 (j)   
    00103cac 67  a4  00       daddiu     param_1 ,sp ,0x0
             00
    00103cb0 0c  04  18       jal        strstr                                           char * strstr(char * __haystack,
             40
    00103cb4 64  a5  09       _daddiu    a1 ,a1 ,0x968
             68
    00103cb8 00  40  28       or         a1 ,v0 ,zero
             25
    00103cbc 0c  04  18       jal        strcmp                                           int strcmp(char * __s1, char * _
             1c
    00103cc0 df  a4  01       _ld        param_1 ,local_30 (sp )
             20
    00103cc4 10  40  00       beq        v0 ,zero ,LAB_00103cdc
             05
    00103cc8 24  02  00       _li        v0 ,0x1
             01
    00103ccc 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             8a
    00103cd0 00  00  10       _or        v0 ,zero ,zero
             25
                         LAB_00103cd4                                    XREF[1]:     00103b80 (j)   
    00103cd4 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             88
    00103cd8 00  00  10       _or        v0 ,zero ,zero
             25
                         LAB_00103cdc                                    XREF[1]:     00103cc4 (j)   
    00103cdc 10  00  ff       b          LAB_00103af8
             86
    00103ce0 ff  90  57       _sd        s0 ,0x57e8 (gp )
             e8
```

seems to call many things meant for finding stuff? This is a function in a usb stack under unix it is written in mips assembly. for those who may not know jal=call.

Comment: TL;DR: it checks some console related stuff (mouse, keyboard) connected to USB. You may try to google for the function if it’s in open source.

Comment: @0andriy why the tldr my text is like 3 lines. Anyway thanks for the info I did google it HEAVILY in every way I could : checkons nothing, check cons, nothing, unix check cons, linux man check cons etc. etc. After about a half an hour of that I came across: check constraints. What specifically in the code shows you its checking the console out of curiosity?

Comment: `TL;DR` in this case is related to my answer, i.o.w. read it as `summary of one may google is that...`.

Answer (score 0):

After using strings command I was able to find That it is related to the keyboard console as 0andriy lead me to believe. The project is not open source.